# creating key=>value pairs with foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, command-line, foreach, iteration

here's my issue:
I have a program in the command line that has access to tens of thousands of users. The idea is that you want to be able to get all the information about a user by simply inputting their username. So, because I want to work in php, I've done the following

```
$user_info = array();
exec('uwdir -v userid=nvidovic', $user_info);
```

To give you an oversimplified version of what a var_dump on $user_info would look like, it would be something like this:

```
array(2){
  [0] => "first: N"
  [1] => "last: Vidovic"
}
```

I'd like to be able to do this $user[first] => N

This is what I've come up with (not for the real data from command line):

```
$full_name = array("first: N", "last: Vidovic");
var_dump($full_name);
foreach ($full_name as $part_name) {
    $exploded = explode(":", $part_name);
    $make_array = array($exploded[0] => $exploded[1]);
    echo $make_array["first"]; 
}
```

Clearly, this doesn't work. But my question is *why*? Does anyone know how I can do what I explained above?
I'm really, really, really...really stuck
THANKS to anyone in advance!!

EDIT:
Great answers, thank you. One last thing though, I keep getting the error messages Notice: Undefined offset: 1  and Notice: Undefined offset: 0 for the code below:

```
$user_info = array();
exec('uwdir -v userid=nvidovic', $user_info); 
foreach ($user_info as $info) {
    $exploded_info = explode(":", $info);
    $info_array[$exploded_info[0]] = $exploded_info[1];
}
echo $info_array["displayName"];
```

Anyone know why this is happening? I thought the explode function would break up the single string into an array of two strings, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$full_name = array("first: N", "last: Vidovic");
//var_dump($full_name);
foreach ($full_name as $part_name) {
    $exploded = explode(":", $part_name);
    $make_array[$exploded[0]] =  $exploded[1];
   // echo $make_array["first"]; 
}
print_r($make_array);
```

http://codepad.org/JvcPdBeq

Comment: all the answers were helpful but this one linked to codepad, which I didn't know existed -- pretty cool. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
$make_array = array($exploded[0] => $exploded[1]);
```

try

```
$make_array[$exploded[0]] = $exploded[1];
```

Make sure you put `$make_array = array();` before this line, just to make sure it's an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Because the line

> $make_array = array($exploded[0] => $exploded[1]);

overwrites the contents of the whole array. So on the last step you will have only one element there.